# How to avoid record duplication in jq

Tags: jq

I've the following Json :

```
{
"hits": {
    "hits": [
        {
            "_source": {
                "offers_data": [
                    {
                        "base_price": 198.89, 
                        "shop_id": 2002, 
                        "shop_name": "TheOtherShop"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "base_price": 223, 
                        "shop_id": 2247, 
                        "shop_name": "MainShop"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "base_price": 225, 
                        "shop_id": 2247, 
                        "shop_name": "MainShop"
                    }
                ], 
                "search_result_data": {
                    "identifiers": {
                        "id": 32116
                    }, 
                    "shop": {
                        "id": 2247, 
                        "name": "MainShop" 
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I'm writing the following command :

```
jq -c --raw-output '.hits.hits[]|{products_ids: ._source.search_result_data.identifiers.id,
best_shop_id: ._source.search_result_data.shop.id,
best_shop_name: (if ._source.search_result_data.shop.id>0 then ._source.search_result_data.shop.id as $shop_id|._source.offers_data[]|select(.shop_id==$shop_id).shop_name else "" end),
best_offer_base_price: (if ._source.search_result_data.shop.id>0 then ._source.search_result_data.shop.id as $shop_id|._source.offers_data[]|select(.shop_id==$shop_id).base_price else "" end)}'
```

and I get this result :

```
{"products_ids":32116,"best_shop_id":2247,"best_shop_name":"MainShop","best_offer_base_price":223}
{"products_ids":32116,"best_shop_id":2247,"best_shop_name":"MainShop","best_offer_base_price":225}
{"products_ids":32116,"best_shop_id":2247,"best_shop_name":"MainShop","best_offer_base_price":223}
{"products_ids":32116,"best_shop_id":2247,"best_shop_name":"MainShop","best_offer_base_price":225}
```

As you can see I get 2 duplicates : Of course I've two offers from MainShop, so it's normal that I get 2 records, but if I'm also fetching the base prices, the it duplicates the result again. In my real world case I get 32 records instead of 2 legitimate ones, because I'm fetching other fields. So I'd like to avoid this extra duplication each time I fetch a field.

The icing on the cake would be to be able to only get one record, the one where amongst Mainshop offers the base_price is the minimum.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Icing

> ... the one where the base_price is the minimum.

The following two interpretations of the problem both assume we can take, as the "minimum" item, any of the admissible items that has the minimal value.

#### First Interpretation of the original question

```
.hits.hits[]._source
| (.offers_data | min_by(.base_price)) as $min_offers_data
| .search_result_data
| {products_ids: .identifiers.id}
  + ($min_offers_data
    | {best_shop_id: .shop_id,
       best_shop_name: .shop_name,
       best_offer_base_price: .base_price})
```

#### Output:

```
{
  "products_ids": 32116,
  "best_shop_id": 2002,
  "best_shop_name": "TheOtherShop",
  "best_offer_base_price": 198.89
}
```

#### Second Interpretation

Restrict consideration to .search_result_data.shop.id:

```
.hits.hits[]._source
| (.search_result_data.shop.id) as $shop
| (.offers_data | map(select(.shop_id == $shop)) | min_by(.base_price)) as $min_offers_data
| .search_result_data
| {products_ids: .identifiers.id}
  + ($min_offers_data
     | {best_shop_id: .shop_id,
        best_shop_name: .shop_name,
        best_offer_base_price: .base_price})
```

#### Output

```
{
  "products_ids": 32116,
  "best_shop_id": 2247,
  "best_shop_name": "MainShop",
  "best_offer_base_price": 223
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Not exactly as the correct icing would be {"products_ids":32116,"best_shop_id":2247,"best_shop_name":"MainShop","best_offer_base_price":223} as I need to get the minimum base price from the mainshop (id 2247) offers

Comment: Please see "Second Interpretation".